# How to protect yourself from argumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, binding, c#-2.0, numericupdown

I have numericUpDown control minValue - 0 maxValue - 100.

I create binding to this control.

If the value changes to 101 will be the exception, which I do not need, and I would like to value is not specifically mentioned.
how to do it ?

**UPDATE:**

```
BindinHelper.BindField(this.nUpDownExecArea, "Value", TempConfigClass, "ExecArea");
```

BindField:

```
public static void BindField(Control control, string propertyName,
               object dataSource, string dataMember)
        {
            Binding bd;

            for (int index = control.DataBindings.Count - 1; (index == 0); index--)
            {
                bd = control.DataBindings[index];
                if (bd.PropertyName == propertyName)
                    control.DataBindings.Remove(bd);
            }
            control.DataBindings.Add(propertyName, dataSource, dataMember, false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        }
```

I set  `TempConfigClass.ExecArea = 99999;`

does not result in errors, but when I go to a tab (tabcontrol) where the error appears to be numericUpDown

Comment: It would probably help if you clarified this question a bit - it may help if you posted a short code sample to clarify the question.

Comment: When you say: "If the value changes to 101" are you referring to programatically in the code?  If that's the case the code is correct, you are setting the value out of range of the min and max you specified.

Comment: The simple solution is do not allow value to be greater then the maxValue.  If you want help you must post what you have.

Comment: @James Michael Hare, I can not get the max and min, I ask where the data context

Comment: @Simply Denis - What do you mean by "I cannot get the max and min" because you should have a reference to the numericUpDown on your main program's window.

Comment: У меня много таких numericUpDown я не хочу проверять каждый из них, хотелось бы массовый способ, просто не допускать такие данные и не выдавать ошибку.

Comment: I have a lot of numericUpDown I do not want to check each of them, I would like massive way, just to prevent such data and do not generate an error.

Comment: @simply denis - You need to check if the numericUpDown.Value is within the min and max range before you increase the Value property.

Answer (score 3):

An argumentOutOfRangeException is telling you that the argument received was *exceptional*.  However if your app is designed in a way to expect certain arguments there are two ways to go about it:

**The recommended way** -
Simply check the value prior to the binding taking place and prevent it going any further if out of range

**or** -
Use a try/catch block to catch the *specific exception* only and deal with it accordingly

Comment: When I ask the data I am far from numericUpDown. and I do not know where to put the try catch

Comment: Where, I do not know where I put the try catch

Comment: @Ramhound - I assumed you could research that yourself ;-) simply denis - Not sure what you're talking about 'far'?

Comment: @m.edmondson - I was saying he didn't post his Try() Catch() statement.  I can write my own trivial code :-)

Comment: @Ramhound - Thought your comment was directed at me